# is there a listener in react or js to fire when another tab in the browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

assume that I have a active react app in a specific tab in the browser. in my react app, I have a component with some data and a button. When I click the button, another tab is opened in the browser. The thing I am looking for is a way to reload my component data when the user close that opened page. Is there a way that I can do something in my react app when another tab in the browser is closed?

I have found some question in here but all of them is about closing the active react app tab not another tab in the browser.

Comment: There is the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) to communicate between tabs. If you'd combine that with an [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event listener and you'll be able to send a message to all other tabs just before a tab closes, notifying the others of the change. Do note: this only works for tabs on the same domain.

Comment: That's not possible as far as I know, and because of security concerns. You don't want some random website to have access to all the other sites you have open in other tabs. They could scrape all the confidential data off that page, or steal local storage tokens from other sites you have open in other tabs. So you shouldn't be trying to do what you're trying to do

Comment: As per the above point, assuming it's the same origin then that's ok, it's still your site. But that's why there's a specific methodology for it rather than it just being a generally available thing in JS